# ASUS P9X79 WS sudden failure

Tags: cpu, motherboard, bios

I used my build for only 4 hours, then suddenly it shut itself down and now refuses to boot.
LED light CPU_LED in glowing blue. According to manual it shows that problem is in CPU.
What might the problem be?
Fans are spinning, CPU is heating up, it does not reboot. No POST, speaker is silent.

Here is my build:

> motherboard: ASUS P9X79 WS;
>
> CPU: Intel Xeon E5-2603;
>
> RAM: Kingston HyperX DDR3 KHX1600C9D3B1/4G

I have tried:

- flushing CMOS
- updating BIOS
- unplugging eveything, but CPU and PSU

Comment: I normally find something is not plugged in correctly and/or there exists a short when a system won't even POST.

Comment: Try the memory pulling technique as well to determine if the cause is the CPU or the RAM.  Pull all the RAM then power up - you should at least get some beep error codes.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a server CPU in a Desktop board... Although the CPU is on the Supported CPU list - it's possible that the EPU switch is causing issues.  Find the switch labeled EPU on your motherboard and toggle it - see if that helps.  If not, try using the MemOK button (Push and hold - wait for like 5 minutes, then power on).

If you do get back into the BIOS, disable any and all overclocking, XMP, etc.  These just seem to cause issues with system stability.